# Unknown requests sent to vue-cli-service not being proxied to backend Rails server

Tags: vue.js

I have vue-cli-service running on port 3001, and my backend rails app running on port 3000.

I want all unknown requests to go to the backend rails app. Reading the vue-cli docs, it would seem that the below code should work, but it doesn't.

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        disableHostCheck: true,
        port: 3001,
        public: '0.0.0.0:3001',
        overlay: {
            warnings: true,
            errors: true
        },
        proxy: 'http://lab.lizardgizzards.com:3000'
    },
    publicPath: "/",
}
```

I have a rails route `/terms` that should render a scaffold page. When I enter `http://lab.lizardgizzards.com:3001/terms` it doesn't render the rails page, it still shows a vue rendering. Shouldn't it render the rails page? Or does this only work for API requests?

Comment: How do you define unknown? Not registered in the vue-router?

Comment: See the webpack documentation to [devServer proxies](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy) and also the documentation about the http-proxy-middleware on which this feature is based on. In each request you can define, if the request goes to your back-end or to the served front-end. You can define a function and read the whole request object. But it seems that you need to manage a list of URLs which should go to the front-end if you want to send everything else to the back-end. It's usually easier to just use a different prefixed endpoint (e.g. `/api`)

Answer (score 1):

Based on [the documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver-proxy) it would seem that what you've done with the `proxy` setting should work. However, it didn't work for me either.

The reason for that is here in the code:

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/9ab0fbde1cf87d888aa3d2c3c52176b8de464c59/packages/%40vue/cli-service/lib/util/prepareProxy.js#L81

If an explicit `context` is set (such as in the example below) it will bail a few lines earlier and everything works fine. Without a `context` it assumes all requests with `accept: text/html` should be `index.html`, presumably for compatibility with history mode routing. Other requests, such as AJAX calls, should be proxied fine.

This did work for me, even for HTML pages.

```js
proxy: {
  '/': {
    target: 'http://lab.lizardgizzards.com:3000'
  }
}
```

Personally I would put the remote server behind its own path to clearly separate it from the UI. e.g.:

```js
proxy: {
  '/api': {
    target: 'http://lab.lizardgizzards.com:3000',
    changeOrigin: true,
    pathRewrite: {
      '^/api': ''
    }
  }
}
```